# JW Flv Player Error handling

Tags: jwplayer

How can I make a trigger that runs if JW Player returns any error.

for example,
when jw player says "video not found", i want to run a ajax function.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few steps here, but the process is basically as follows:

- Wait for the player to be ready
- Add an error event listener with a callback function
- Your callback function will be triggered when an error occurs.

The code for that looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var player;

    function playerReady(obj) {
    player = document.getElementById(obj['id']);
        player.addModelListener('ERROR', errorHandler);
    };

    function errorHandler(evt){
        //Your Code Here
    }
</script>
```

You should check out the documentation for more information on [events you can listen for](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player4Events) and [adding event listeners](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player4Api).

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video